# Create Sea Surface Plot with Matplotlib3D wireframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to create a plot which looks similar to: https://www.shutterstock.com/de/image-vector/vector-abstract-3d-wave-wireframe-surrounding-445020520
I use something like the wire frame demo with a different background (best case a blue color gradient):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d', axisbg='blue')

# Grab some test data, e.g.gcreate noisy sea surface data
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)

# Plot a basic white wireframe for the surface
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cstride=10, color='white')

plt.show()
```

What would you take to make this more look like the example?

Cheers Bene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one (out of many) options. Using a surface plot in the background of the wireframe can give the plot some shading and make it more look like the picture.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d', facecolor='#1a5a98')
plt.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1)
fig.patch.set_color('#1a5a98')

#Generate some data
x = np.linspace(0,500,501)/(9*np.pi)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,x)
f = lambda x,y: np.sin(x+y**0.2)*np.cos(y-x**0.4)
Z = f(X,Y)

# plot surface, for nice shading
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cstride=10)
# plot wireframe for white lines on top
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cstride=10, color='white', linewidth=0.5)
#set axis off
ax.axis("off")
ax.set_xlim(6.42,11.17)
ax.set_ylim(6.42,11.17)
ax.set_zlim(-6,6)
ax.view_init(elev=25, azim=-88)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you like this solution, you may upvote it. But if I were you, I would wait before accepting the answer. There are possibly other solutions and when accepting the answer people might not care to look at the question anymore.